# How not to add current page to browser history

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a little question. I have a login page that after login redirects me to a different page. How can i make this page to not be added to browser history so that when i go back from a third page, to redirect me to the login page? I heard about html5's newest additions like pushState(), replaceState() but i don't really know how to use them or even if they suit my problem. Thanks.

Comment: does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290055/how-do-i-remove-a-page-from-the-browser-history

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using BBQ with JQuery, I have used it before as a project for work and it really worked wonders for me, it uses the pushState(), replaceState() and getState() as you mentioned, but as opposed to using HTML5, it will work on IE

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/

Hope you work it out!

Comment: its a bit fuzzy. I dont really get how to use it.

Comment: I could sit here and explain how to use the lot of it but unfortunately I don't have the character limit to do that, if you give it a try and get stuck with the code then come back to me I'll be more than happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Added this before redirecting

```
window.history.replaceState( {} , 'title', 'page' );
```

where page=name of your preveious page, title = the title of preveious page(currently not working)